# How to invoke an app through the iOS 8 Share Menu?

Tags: xcode, ios8, ios8-share-extension

I created a `Single View Application` in Xcode and added a `Share Extension` target called "Add Note" to it.
After selecting "Add Note" from the Share Menu in Safari, [a widget](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/master/screenshots/screenshot-ios7-share.png) gets invoked instead of my actual *full app*.
What do I need to change to get my full app invoked instead of the widget?

Comment: You can't, the share extension uses it own view. The share extensions are ment to start the full app.

Comment: You wrote both time "share extensions" - I'm confussed.

Comment: Sorry the is the word not, missing, a share extension is not ment to start a full app. The idea is the extension show a simple view which allows the user to share some content.

Comment: OK, but how to invoke the full app from the Share Menu? Do I need a Action Extension for that or some other kind of "hack"? (I can't remember the apps name but it's definitely prossible to "skip" the widget)

Comment: Well it is not ment to do it, but you could just extend the share view to match you full app I guess. But are you sure you want a share extension then, since the share extension is just for share some information with other app or site.

Comment: My goal is that a user can send a link, image or text from the Share Menu to my "full" app. What kind of extension is the best for the job?